# How to link 2 static libraries to one Code::Blocks project

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I have 3 code "chunks" for my project: 2 static libraries: LibraryA and LibraryB, and a console application: Client.

The client calls LibraryA and LibraryA calls LibraryB.  The client does NOT use LibraryB at all.

Right now, I have Library A compiled just fine but when I try to compile the client I get an error because it cannot locate LibraryB. Here is what the Build Log says leading upt to the error:

```
g++ -L/path/to/LibraryA -L/path/to/LibraryB/ -o bin/Debug/Client obj/Debug/main.o   LibraryA.a "LibraryB.a"
LibraryA.a(LibraryA.o): In function `LibraryA_Class::function(args)':
LibraryA.cpp:136: undefined reference to `namespace::LibraryB::LibraryB_class()'
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, any help is appreciated. 
I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 in Ubuntu 14.04 (VirtualBox) with the GNU GCC Compiler

Thanks in advance.
Let me know if more information is needed.

**Update**

I modified the settings to take out the -L commands at the beginning so now it looks like this (with the actual library names):

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/Client obj/Debug/main.o   ../../Wrapper/FCS_PlanTrajectory/bin/Debug/libFCS_PlanTrajectory.a ../../BAE/lib_obj/libCMetInterpIf.a
../../Wrapper/FCS_PlanTrajectory/bin/Debug/libFCS_PlanTrajectory.a(PlanTrajectory.o): In function `PlanTrajectory_Class::planSingleTrajectory(unsigned char, Position_T const&, double, double*, Position_T const&, unsigned char, std::vector<agsfirecontrol::METOCGridPoint_T, std::allocator<agsfirecontrol::METOCGridPoint_T> > const&, unsigned char, double, double, double*, Position_T*, double&, double&, unsigned int&, agsfirecontrol::AgsFireControlCompliance_T&)':
/home/angela/Work/FCS/Code/Wrapper/FCS_PlanTrajectory/src/PlanTrajectory.cpp:136: undefined reference to `agsfirecontrol::CMetInterpIf::CMetInterpIf()'
/home/angela/Work/FCS/Code/Wrapper/FCS_PlanTrajectory/src/PlanTrajectory.cpp:193: undefined reference to `agsfirecontrol::CMetInterpIf::~CMetInterpIf()'
/home/angela/Work/FCS/Code/Wrapper/FCS_PlanTrajectory/src/PlanTrajectory.cpp:193: undefined reference to `agsfirecontrol::CMetInterpIf::~CMetInterpIf()'
```

LibraryA = PlanTrajectory, LibraryB = CMetInterpIf

The second 2 errors have always been present also if that helps at all. Btw, I'm using relative paths because eventually I need this to be portable to another machine. I can change to absolute paths if it will help anything

```
nm -C libCMetInterpIf.a | fgrep 'agsfirecontrol::CMetInterpIf::CMetInterpIf()'
nm: CEnvironment.o: no symbols
nm: CMetInterpIf.o: no symbols
nm: CMathUtilities.o: no symbols
```

Comment: Please show your actual link command and actual error message. Substituting "LibraryA.a" in place of the actual linker argument may change meaning of the command.

Comment: Do this command `nm -C libCMetInterpIf.a | fgrep 'agsfirecontrol::CMetInterpIf::CMetInterpIf()'`. See any output?

Comment: You have a bad library. How do you build it?

Comment: Dang! I wasted a lot of time on this! That library is from a third party so I'm not sure how it is built. Thanks for your input @n.m., I will be working with the third party to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

In order to successfully link, you need to provide the linker with *all* the libraries needed by the program, including those that are dependencies of other libraries. Your client program may not directly call things in LibraryB, but it is still a dependency, because LibraryA needs it. Try this:

```
g++ -o bin/Debug/Client obj/Debug/main.o /path/to/LibraryA.a /path/to/LibraryB.a
```

There's not really a need for the `-L/path/to/libraryA ... LibraryA.a` verbosity - you can either do like above, naming the files directly, or, assuming your libraries are named using the more standard pattern of `libA.a`, you can use `-L/path/to/libraryA ... -lA` - the `-l<something>` flag searches for a library named `lib<something>.a` or `lib<something>.so`.